# bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pycharm

I can not install psycopg2. I try to change the DB from sqlite to postgesql but get always the same error. I also tried to install it via the project interpreter instead of my terminal but get :

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

(venv) localhost:mysite Sergio$ pip install psycopg2
bash: /Users/Sergio/PycharmProjects/#WE_GRAPPLE/venv/bin/pip: /Users/Sergio/PycharmProjects/#WE_GRAPPLE/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
(venv) localhost:mysite Sergio$
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have Permission to pip, you can change to root

```
su root
```

enter your root password and then

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: I tried it, but still no solution. Do you have any other suggestion what could cause the error ?

Comment: when you su root, do you still have bad permission?

Comment: Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Now there is a different ERROR.

Comment: Sorry about that ,I don't know how to fix it .